# graph confidence intervals on ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

[edited]I am trying to graph confidence intervals onto a ggvis plot. I have a df with 6 columns:

```
Test  Region   X   lower_X  upper_X   N.weekly
 ili   Reg1    5     1         9        100
 ili   Reg1    3     2         19       133
 ili   Reg2    4     1         7        120
 pos   Reg1    6     2         9        200
 pos   Reg1    7     1         12       300
 pos   Reg2    5     2         5        180

DF<- data.frame( X =  1:10
         ,Mean = c(NA,NA, .2,.23,.26,.28,.3,.31,.33,.35)
         ,N.weekly = c(NA, 7,12,16,20,24.8,29,33,37,41)
         ,CrI_Low = c(NA, -.13, -.11, -.09, -.06, -.03,0, 0, 0.02, 0.04)
         ,CrI_High = c(NA, .54,.54,.58,.57,.61,.58,.60,.61,.61)
         ,region = "Region 1"
         ,test = "ili")

DF %>%
  group_by(region, test) %>%
  ggvis(x = ~N.weekly, y = ~Mean, stroke = ~test) %>%
  layer_smooths()
```

The above code provides a nice plot of the 20 lines, but I would like for each line to be surrounded with its corresponding confidence interval in a translucent ribbon.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible in its present form, however, you should be able to add, `layer_model_prediction(model = "loess", se = TRUE)`. For example (and reproducible): `mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, fill = ~factor(cyl), stroke = ~factor(cyl)) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_model_predictions(model = "loess", se = TRUE)`